# Implementing ASP.NET MVC error handling using Castle Windsor's Dynamic Proxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I spent a long time trying to get the ASP.NET MVC [[HandleError] attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to work in my websites. It seemed like a good idea to go with the solution offered by the framework, but I just couldn't get it to do anything useful. Then I tried writing my own attribute (mainly so that I could step in to the code with the debugger), but although my code seemed to be doing all the right things, after it executed the framework took over and did mysterious things. Finally I tried the MVC Contrib's [[Rescue] attribute](https://github.com/atomicobject/mvccontrib/blob/master/src/MVCContrib/Filters/RescueAttribute.cs), which was better but I still couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

One problem is that exceptions thrown in code embedded in aspx / ascx pages get wrapped in HttpException's and WebHttpException's.

Another problem for me was that the system is very opaque. I was essentially poking inputs in to a black box with some desired outputs in mind, but with no idea (other than the documentation, which doesn't seem very accurate / thorough) what the relationship was between them.

So, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I went for [Dynamic Proxies in Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), using the code below, which tries to handle Database errors, for which I have a specific Exception (AccessDBException).

The _alreadyAttemptedToShowErrorPage is to stop infinite recursion in the case where the error page throws an Exception.

The GetAccessDBException(...) method finds the relevant exception anywhere in the Exception stack, for the case when there are problems in aspx / ascx code.

The code requires that there is a BaseController class that all controllers derive from. This class is used to add a CreateErrorView(...) method (being as the standard View(...) method is protected)

```
public class AccessDBExceptionHandlingDynamicProxy : IInterceptor
{
    private bool _alreadyAttemptedToShowErrorPage;

    public AccessDBExceptionHandlingDynamicProxy()
    {
        _alreadyAttemptedToShowErrorPage = false;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Contract.Requires(invocation.Proxy is BaseController);

        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            if (_alreadyAttemptedToShowErrorPage == true) throw e;
            _alreadyAttemptedToShowErrorPage = true;

            var dbException = GetAccessDBException(e);

            if (dbException != null)
            {
                var baseController = (invocation.Proxy as BaseController);
                var view = baseController.CreateErrorView("AccessDBException", new AccessDBExceptionViewModel(dbException));

                baseController.Response.Clear();
                baseController.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; 
                view.ExecuteResult(baseController.ControllerContext);
                baseController.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private static AccessDBException GetAccessDBException(HttpException e)
    {
        AccessDBException dbException = null;
        Exception current = e;

        while (dbException == null && current != null)
        {
            if (current is AccessDBException) dbException = (current as AccessDBException);
            current = current.InnerException;
        }

        return dbException;
    }
}
```